# White Screen pops and and then it gets back to previous activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a sign up page and in previous activity I ask user to select if they are an existing or new user. I have written code for new user (i.e. registration), but when I click on new user activity (intent), a white screen pops up and it again gets back to select type of user.

Here's the code for new user registration:

```
package com.example.houserentappproject;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class activity_registration_user extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText userFullName , userEmail , userPassword , userContact ;
    Button btn_register ;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase ;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference ;
    userInfo userInfo ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_user);



        userFullName = findViewById(R.id.id_fullname_newuser);
        userEmail = findViewById(R.id.id_email_newuser);
        userPassword = findViewById(R.id.id_password_newuser);
        userContact = findViewById(R.id.id_mobileno_newuser);
        btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_regitser);

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("userInfo");

        userInfo = new userInfo();

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String name = userFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = userEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = userPassword.getText().toString();
                String mobileNo = userContact.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && TextUtils.isEmpty(mobileNo)) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity_registration_user.this, "Please Add some data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    addUserInfoToFirebase(name, email , password , mobileNo);
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , activity_successful_google_signin.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }

            private void addUserInfoToFirebase(String name, String email, String password, String mobileNo) {

                userInfo.setUserFullName(name);
                userInfo.setUserEmail(email);
                userInfo.setUserPassword(password);
                userInfo.setUserContact(mobileNo);

                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        databaseReference.setValue(userInfo);
                        Toast.makeText(activity_registration_user.this, "Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity_registration_user.this, "Registration Failed" + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I think that happen because use finish() inside onclick event